# How to periodically call a background process in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, scheduling, background-process

I have a background process/function that I want to execute every 2 mins, in my application. It checks for any events for that current time in the database and displays the events list if there are any.

For this purpose I have found following two approaches:

1. Using a **backgroundworker process** in ASP.NET. (But I am not aware of how to call it every 2 mins of time elapsed.)
2. Tried to search for solution using **Windows Service that calls my WebService**. (But couldn't find any help in this also.)

So please provide me a better solution to my problem.

Comment: Where do you want to display the events list?

Comment: actually, it checks for any event type, and adds it in to the "Alerts" table of my database...
But this task should occur after every 2 mins , in my application.

Comment: That does not answers Sergeys question. You wrote, you want to *display* the list somewhere from your backgroundtask. Where and how?

Comment: Ohh... I m so sorry Sir....
To be more specific , in my application, I do not want the records to be displayed, I want if the CurrentDatetime == EventStartDatetime, then I want to insert that event into the "Alerts" table....And from the alerts table, it would be displayed on the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here , we can also use a different approach  ..

1)Create a ASP.Net  Windows Service application.
You have to specify the URL of your WebService which needs to be called from your ASP.Net application in this Windows Service(Most probably in App.Config of windows service).

2)Add a "Web Reference" of your web service in your Windows Service.

3)Created a method in that windows service that will have a method that will be called after a specific time interval (say every 2 mins )

3)Now,When this windows service method gets invoked after the Timer has elapsed , It will call the Web Service Methods in your ASP.NET application,

4) Create a setup of that windows service and install wherever required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Thread with that process/function. the function need to be something like this:

```
public void myfunctionloop()
{
   while(true)
   {
     //do your stuff
     wait 2 mins
   }
}
```

that way, you will have a thread doing your method every 2 mins while your application is running like always in the main thread.

take a look to this webs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164128.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38501/Multi-Threading-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

You can use BackgroundWorker Class to do this.. try creating an instance in Application_Start and Dispose it when Application_End Event.

For more information have a look at this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34968/Use-NET-s-BackgroundWorker-to-Keep-ASP-NET-Cache-i

Answer (score 0):

[Quartz Scheduler](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) is a better solution.  It gives you good number of options.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a timer, declared in global.asax, like this:

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 2000 * 60;
        timer.Elapsed += Myhandler;
        timer.Start();

        Application.Add("timer", timer);
    }

    static void Myhandler(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make simple Windows service that calls some page or better ashx handler in your ASP.NET application. Create Windows service and in it call ashx handler. Something like this:

```
  public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
  {
    private Timer serviceTimer = new Timer();

    public Service1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
      this.serviceTimer.Interval = (1000 * 60) * 2;  // TWO minutes
      this.serviceTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DoWork);
      this.serviceTimer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
      this.serviceTimer.Stop();
    }

    void DoWork(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      WebClient wc = new WebClient();
      wc.DownloadData("http://www.yoursite.com/checkevents.ashx");
    }

  }
```

Or you can use a hack with cache expiration, you can see complete example and code here:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Comment: Thank you for your reply antonio, but I am not familiar of how to work out my scenario with , handler(ashx) file....
Could you please guide me in this. ?

Comment: You can also use plain aspx page, but ashx is far more suited for this case, look here : http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

Answer (score -1):

You can use a timer to call a background thread after certain time interval.

Threading will be as:

```
protected void BackGroundJob() 
{ 
    //Your code goes here
} 

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BackGroundJob)); 
    t.Start(); 
}
```

On every tickinng of timer it will call the background process. Customize the timer accordingly.